# iOS App how long it takes to get Export Compliance

Tags: ios, time, submit

This might be a bit off topic. But I am desperate now :). My app has been submitted for 2 weeks and it is still stuck at the "Waiting for Export Compliance" status. Anyone has the similar experience? How long is this step? Thanks!

Comment: While this is probably off-topic I'd love to know myself since I am in the same position - day 13 and counting for me. I started a thread on the Apple dev forums: https://devforums.apple.com/message/1023459#1023459

Comment: See the thread I linked to for a possible resolution to your issue.